# file_get_contents array foreach

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Здравствуйте ! Прошу помочь 
Основная проблема тут как считаю я

```
foreach (file_get_html($links,true) as $lik) {
    foreach ($lik->find('.iteminfo-item-border .iteminfo-title-2 a') as $aa) {
        $linksa[] = "http://kotlant.ua" . $aa->href;
    }
}
```

Вот весь код

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";
ini_set('allow_url_fopen','1');


// Получаем ссылки на товары
$html_category = file_get_html('http://kotlant.ua/kg/tverdotoplivnye-kotly/');
$links = array();

// Получаем ссылки на товары с предложениями
foreach($html_category->find('.itemcat-item-border .item-cat-button a') as $a) {
    $links[] = "http://kotlant.ua".$a->href;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($links);
echo "</pre>";
echo "Товаров - ".count($links);

foreach (file_get_html($links,true) as $lik) {
    foreach ($lik->find('.iteminfo-item-border .iteminfo-title-2 a') as $aa) {
        $linksa[] = "http://kotlant.ua" . $aa->href;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($linksa);
echo "</pre>";
echo "Товаров - ".count($linksa);
```

Ошибки

```
    Array
(
    [0] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/15/
    [1] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/16/
    [2] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/17/
    [3] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/18/
    [4] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/19/
    [5] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/22/
    [6] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/27/
    [7] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/30/
    [8] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/40/
    [9] => http://kotlant.ua/kg/50/
)
Товаров - 10
Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in parser/project/gazal/kotlant/simple_html_dom.php on line 76

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in parser/project/gazal/kotlant/index.php on line 20


Notice:  Undefined variable: linksa in parser/project/gazal/kotlant/index.php on line 26


Notice: Undefined variable: linksa in parser/project/gazal/kotlant/index.php on line 28
Товаров - 0
Notice: Undefined variable: linksa in parser/project/gazal/kotlant/index.php on line 31


Notice:  Undefined variable: articles in parser/project/gazal/kotlant/index.php on line 77


Notice: Undefined variable: articles in parser/project/gazal/kotlant/index.php on line 87

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in parser/project/gazal/kotlant/index.php on line 87
```

Comment: на сколько я помню, `file_get_html()` корректно работает только с валидным html. Попробуйте вместо `file_get_html()` получать контент с помощью `file_get_contents()`, а полученную строку передавайте на обработку функции `str_get_html()`.

Comment: вам написано что ожидается строка, вы передаете массив. должно быть `foreach($links as $l){ $html = file_get_html($l); ... }` а не наоборот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Основная проблема тут как считаю я

Правильно считаете, и об этом вам говорит и сам пхп. Функция `file_get_html` первым параметром ожидает путь к файлу или ссылку. Вы же передаете массив ссылок, в результате чего получаете соответствующее уведомление

> Warning: `file_get_contents()`expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, **array given**

Так что код следует изменить примерно следующим образом

```
$linksa = [];
foreach ($links as $url){
    $lik = file_get_html($url);
    if(!$lik) continue;

    $items = $lik->find('.iteminfo-item-border .iteminfo-title-2 a');
    foreach ($items as $aa) {
       $linksa[] = "http://kotlant.ua" . $aa->href;
    }
}
```